# AlarmManager doesn't do anything

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make an Alarm using the Alarm Manager. The app runs without any error messages, but nothing happens.

I tried solutions from developer.android.com and suggestions from stackoverflow.
I also tried copying a complete tutorial i found, but nothing worked.

The app runs on API22 and was tested on an emulator(API23) and a real device(API22).

This is my Code:

MainActivity.java startAlarm():

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,myIntent,0);

manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+3000,pendingIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver.java:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"THIS IS MY ALARM",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml, between `<manifest...>` and `</manifest>`:

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: your timebase is wrong feel free to read the documentation!  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html`RTC_WAKEUP` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` as its time base.

Comment: @escape-llc That's true, but with that combination, the given time would be in the past, so the alarm would fire immediately, instead of not doing anything.

Comment: Where is the `<receiver>` element in the manifest? It needs to be between the `<application>` tags, but not inside anything else, like `<activity>` or `<service>` tags.

Comment: @Mike M. the <receiver> was outside the <application> tags, it now works thank you so much

Comment: and also thanks to @escape-llc

Answer (score 2):

your reciever name is `AlarmToastReceiver` not `AlarmReceiver`

try:

```
   <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmToastReceiver "></receiver>
```

Comment: my apologies, thats just a mistake i made when i copied my code here.